# Changes to bootstrap4.css are not reflected

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build a .NET Core web app that uses NPM.

In package.json I can see:

```
"bootstrap": "4.1.1"
```

However, when I make changes to bootstrap4.css, nothing gets reflected, even if I do "Empty cache and hard reload" in Chrome. It seems I have to somehow remake the bundle.

Any suggestions?

(I'm sorry if it's a bit newbie...!)

Comment: what are you changing in bootstrap css file? did you rename the bootstrap file to what you have above? Is bootstrap declared in your head element? i'd suggest making changes in your own css file, it might be easier to identify the problem.

Comment: Yes, that (making changes in your own css file) did the trick. Thanks for answering!

Comment: awesome - glad that was able to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem description is not quite clear. So I would suggest you to:

- check your link to your css file.
- Make Sure your Bootstrap files are included in your project.

Hope it helps.